# NsPerstentContainer name in Appdelegate conventions in Core Data setup

Tags: swift, core-data

I'm programming my fist SwiftApp got stuck setting up Core data. Since I'm integrating it into existing code I can't have Xcode set it up on Prohect init anymore. Furthermore I als want to understand what the lines of code actually do. Since all Core libraries are secret I am stuck with Apple's Docs which are not very clear on the matter.

Pfew... with that out of the way here is the question; What is the significance of the name passed to...

```
let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Core_Data")
```

...in the App Delegate file. I had set it up before but during compilation Xcode complained that it could not find the specified Name's module. Changing it to my project's name, the core data file I had created or the name of the Database passed to the menu when adding a Core Data file did not seem to help at all. Searching the web and a few tutorials people just fly over it and it is still very much unclear to me.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string passed there is used for two things. If you were to pass the string `Foo`, Core Data would attempt:

- To find the data model by looking for `Foo.xcdatamodel` or `Foo.xcdatamodeld`.
- To find (or create) the persistent store, using the name `Foo.sqlite`.

Even an incorrect string value (i.e. one that doesn't match the name of your data model) should not cause a compilation error. It might cause an error at run time if iOS can't find the named data model.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear explanation. It turned out I had forgotten to set the Class Module!